# Previous and next buttons - expand hidden panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iphone

I have a form which consists of multiple panels. Each panel is collapsed (display:none) until the user touches the caption/bar to uncollapse it, except the first. So my problem is when I get to the last input on my expanded form I can't focus on the next input element(with the next button on iOS) because it's not displayed. Im thinking a invisible element after the last element on my form, that when it gains focus it expands the collapsed panel underneeth. Hope that makes sense. 
Regards.

Comment: And your mark-up? JavaScript? Anything that we can work on, other than a vague description of what you 'think' might be happening?

Comment: Please show some HTML/CSS/JS. jsFiddle is a good point to start...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but I figured it out. I used an input at the last element in the form to detect focus and collapse the next panel. Like done here http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=130036

Tnks